# Grouping like values into one and adding associated COUNTS

Tags: sql, count, oracle10g

Again, I apologize for my lack of knowledge in advance.  If I need to add anything to help you answer my question, please just ask.  Here goes....

I have this set of data:

```
PERMIT                              # OF PERMITS
Individual NPDES w/ construction    0   
Individual NPDES w/o construction   0   
Renewals (COWS)                     2   
Approvals w/ Construction           21  
Renewals (CHICKENS)                 25  
Approvals w/ Construction           1   
Approvals w/o construction          1   
Renewals (CHICKENS)                 1
```

What I need to do is combine the like terms in the PERMIT column and add the associated counts from the # of permits.  Can this be done?  Thank you in advance.

System: Oracle 10g

Comment: What tables do you have to work with?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried what @Deif suggested below about adding a dummy column and grouping based on that column, but it did not work (unless I am attempting it wrong).  I ended up with the rows next to one another, but not grouped.

There are 4 tables to work with but all of the important values (as relevant to this question, come out of 1 table and are mostly 'DECODE`s of a single field, DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST.  The main problem is that the # of Permits column is `COUNT(DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST)` where in the final product I will need the values from that column added...

Comment: ...together where the values in "Project Type" are the same.  Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's going to be difficult to group rows on a subjective basis and I would not advise you to go down that route. Instead you should create a third column called 'PERMIT GROUP' so you can group each permit together. The query for what you want becomes simple once this is done.

Comment: How would I group each permit together, as opposed to grouping based on that column?  I have created the dummy column, but grouping based on that column only places the identical permit rows adjacent to one another.  Thank you

Comment: Also, is this grouping going to `SUM` the previously `COUNT`ed rows in the # of PERMITS column?

Comment: It depends what query you have done and what groups you have put in. I have made this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c86d/1) for you to look at and hopefully it will help you.

Comment: I was grouping incorrectly.  Once I grouped by a few things and `SUM`med the # of Permits, it worked!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with analytic functions. You need to partition your data by permits and calc. totals withing the partition. Here's general example based on Oracle scott.emp table where you see count(*) within that deptno only. Dept = 10 has 3 employess, 20 has 5 etc...:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT deptno, ename, job, sal,
     COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) cnt
   FROM scott.emp)
  -- WHERE deptno = 10 -- optional 
 /

DEPTNO  ENAME   JOB         SAL     CNT
-------------------------------------------------------
10      CLARK   MANAGER     2450    3
10      KING    PRESIDENT   5000    3
....
20      JONES   MANAGER     2975    5
20      FORD    ANALYST     3000    5
....
30      WARD    SALESMAN    1250    6
30      TURNER  SALESMAN    1500    6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT permitgroup, SUM(nrOfpermits)
FROM (SELECT substr(permit,1,instr(permit,' ')-1) permitgroup, nrOfpermits
      FROM permits)
GROUP BY permitgroup
```

Assuming that "like terms" means starting with the same word, but you could easily change your similarity criteria by modifying the inner SELECT statement.

[Test Code](http://pastebin.com/x95DtYTU)

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you have a `permits` table that has a list of all the permit values.

```
select p.permit, count(a.ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST) as NumPermits
from Permits p left outer join
     DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST a
     on p.permit = a.permit   -- assuming join is on the actual name
group by p.permit
order by 1
```

I think the challenge is getting the `0` counts.  You do this with a list of all values you would want (I call this the "driver") and then left joining in the rest of the data.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing.  It turns out I was grouping incorrectly.  Thank you very much for the help!